# termios: XON/XOFF handshake

Tags: serial-port, termios

I'm trying to send data using the XON/XOFF software handshake so the receiver may control the data flow by using control characters.

To enable the flow control for sending data I did this:

> tcgetattr (fd, &options) ;            // Read current options
>   options.c_cflag |= IXON ;             // Enable XON flow control on output
>   tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &options) ;   // Set new options

The program takes a file and sends it byte by byte to the serial interface.
Curiously, when receiving the default STOP (0x13) the program continues sending data.
When checking VSTOP for its value it returns 0x09. But this (0x09) also doesn't work for a STOP.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this XON/XOFF to work with termios?

Thanks!
-Sören

Answer (score 1):

The sender does not need immediately stop if XOFF is received. It can still flush its output puffer. Therefore, the receiver should send XOFF already when it has still enough space to receive some more data (e.g. 30 bytes free).

VSTOP is just a flag (therefore an arbitrary integer, varying on different platforms) and not the ASCII character for XOFF.

Comment: I understand. What I've also tried is to add a delay of 1ms after ech byte sent. Doesn't work.    Another aproach for my application could be to limit the size of the output buffer to e.g. 5 bytes. How could that be achieved?

Comment: In my (long) experience with serial comms, the sender *does* stop as soon as XOFF is received, although a couple of bytes may slip by before it's processed, which is why in PC-AT times with 80386 processors it was recommended to use a separate serial IO card with a 16550 UART chip. VSTOP should be 0x13 or ctrl-S; what does `stty -a < /dev/ttyS0` (modify device if necessary) show?

Comment: It just came to me that the `0x09` you found for `VSTOP` is the index into the `c_cc[]` array of special characters. You should check `options.c_cc[VSTOP]` to see what the actual value of the VSTOP character is.